# SharePoint 2010 Workflow Platform for SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow

I want to create workflow in SharePoint 2013 using SPD2013. When i try to create wrokflow for selected List i see dropdown to select Platform Type: SharePoint 2010 Workflow only. (I understand that The option for SharePoint 2013 Workflow platform is not available because we have not installed and configured Workflow Manager for SharePoint 2013). But my question is can i still create workflow using (Platform Type: SharePoint 2010 Workflow) for my SharePoint 2013 List ? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are right.

- for SPD 2013 workflows you need Workflow manager...2013 requires Windows Workflow Foundation 4, for this we need WF manager n SP 2013.
- without workflow manager you can only create 2010 workflows...2010 requires Windows Workflow Foundation 3 which automatically install with sp 2013...

Comment: Thanks Waqas for your help. So that means in my case i can only create workflows using SPD 2013 for SP2010 Lists and not for SP2013 Lists.

Comment: Without wfm you will not get the option of 2013 workflows